# Dynamic Input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

I want to make input fields dynamic.
According to the user-selected option in one dropdown, I have to change to another select option, and also user can add more input fields and delete them.
I'm able to change according to users selection but now how I add more fields and delete it dynamically.
--- script ----

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#standardone").change(function() {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
          var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
          if (optionValue == "ss") {
            $("#select1").show();
            $("#select2").hide();
            $("#select3").hide();
            $("#select4").hide();
            $("#select5").hide();
            $("#medium1").show();
            $("#board1").show();
          }
          if (optionValue == "C_1-4" || optionValue == "C_5-8" || optionValue == "C_9" || optionValue == "C_10" || optionValue == "C_9-10" || optionValue == "11-12_C") {
            $("#select1").show();
            $("#select2").hide();
            $("#select3").hide();
            $("#select4").hide();
            $("#select5").hide();
            $("#medium1").show();
            $("#board1").show();
          }
          if (optionValue == "11-12_S") {
            $("#select1").hide();
            $("#select2").hide();
            $("#select3").hide();
            $("#select4").show();
            $("#select5").hide();
            $("#medium1").show();
            $("#board1").show();
          }
          if (optionValue == "IIT-JEE") {
            $("#select1").hide();
            $("#select2").show();
            $("#select3").hide();
            $("#select4").hide();
            $("#select5").hide();
            $("#medium1").show();
            $("#board1").show();
          }
          if (optionValue == "NEET") {
            $("#select1").hide();
            $("#select2").hide();
            $("#select3").show();
            $("#select4").hide();
            $("#select5").hide();
            $("#medium1").show();
            $("#board1").show();
          }
          if (optionValue == "For_lang") {
            $("#select1").hide();
            $("#select2").hide();
            $("#select3").hide();
            $("#select4").hide();
            $("#medium1").hide();
            $("#board1").hide();
            $("#select5").show();
          }
        });
      }).change();    
    });
 </script>
```

---- body ----

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 ">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name_of_business" class="font-weight-bold coac fw-bold">Standard</label>
                    <br>

                    <select name="std1" class="font-weight-bold" id="standardone">
                      <option value="ss">Select Standard</option>
                      <option value="C_1-4">Class 1-4</option>
                      <option value="C_5-8">Class 5-8</option>
                      <option value="C_9">Class 9</option>
                      <option value="C_10">Class 10</option>
                      <option value="11-12_C">11th-12th Commerce</option>
                      <option value="11-12_S">11th-12th Science</option>
                      <option value="IIT-JEE">IIT-JEE</option>
                      <option value="NEET">NEET</option>
                      <option value="For_lang">Foreign Langauges</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="font-weight-bold fw-bold">Subjects</label>
                    <br>
                    <select name="sub11" class="font-weight-bold" id="select1">
                      <option value="ss">Select Subject</option>
                      <option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="sub12" class="font-weight-bold" id="select2">
                      <option value="ss">Select Subject</option>
                      <option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>
                      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                      <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="sub13" class="font-weight-bold" id="select3">
                      <option value="ss">Select Subject</option>
                      <option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>
                      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                      <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="sub14" class="font-weight-bold" id="select4">
                      <option value="ss">Select Subject</option>
                      <option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>
                      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                      <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
                      <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="sub15" class="font-weight-bold" id="select5">
                      <option value="ss">Select Languge</option>
                      <option value="Spoken_English">Spoken English</option>
                      <option value="German">German</option>
                      <option value="French">French</option>
                      <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, it may help you.

---------body------------

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 ">   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name_of_business" class="font-weight-bold coac fw-bold">Standard</label>
    <br>

    <select name="std1" class="font-weight-bold" id="standardone">
      <option value="ss">Select Standard</option>
      <option value="C_1-4">Class 1-4</option>
      <option value="C_5-8">Class 5-8</option>
      <option value="C_9">Class 9</option>
      <option value="C_10">Class 10</option>
      <option value="11-12_C">11th-12th Commerce</option>
      <option value="11-12_S">11th-12th Science</option>
      <option value="IIT-JEE">IIT-JEE</option>
      <option value="NEET">NEET</option>
      <option value="For_lang">Foreign Langauges</option>
    </select>   </div> </div>

<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold fw-bold">Subjects</label>
    <br>
    <select name="sub11" class="font-weight-bold" id="select1">
      <option value="ss">Select Subject</option>
      <option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>
    </select>   </div> </div>
```

---------script----------

```
<script>
var _select2="Physics,Chemistry,Maths";
var _select3="Physics,Chemistry,Biology";
var _select4="Physics,Chemistry,Maths,Biology";
var _select5="Spoken_English,German,French,Spanish";
    $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $("#standardone").change(function(e) {
            var optionValue = $(this).val();
                    var _optionsToAdd="";
                    
                    $("#select1").html('<option value="ss">Select Subject</option><option value="all_sub">All Subjects</option>');
                    
                    if (optionValue == "ss" || optionValue == "C_1-4" || optionValue == "C_5-8" || optionValue == "C_9" || optionValue == "C_10" || optionValue == "C_9-10" || optionValue == "11-12_C") {
                        _optionsToAdd="";
                    }
                    if (optionValue == "11-12_S") {
                        _optionsToAdd=_select4;
                    }
                    if (optionValue == "IIT-JEE") {
                        _optionsToAdd=_select2;
                    }
                    if (optionValue == "NEET") {
                        _optionsToAdd=_select3;
                    }
                    if (optionValue == "For_lang") {
                        _optionsToAdd=_select5;
                    }
                    if(_optionsToAdd!=="")
                    {
                         var _arr=_optionsToAdd.split(",");
                         var _count=_arr.length;
                         var _existHtml = $("#select1").html();
                         for(var _byt=0; _byt<_count; _byt++)
                         {
                             var _data=_arr[_byt];
                             _existHtml+='<option value="'+_data+'">'+_data+'</option>';
                         }
                         $("#select1").html(_existHtml);
                    }
      });  
    });
 </script>
```